# Tracing on Canvas in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to trace a alphabet.I have displayed the arrow key which gives the right way to trace the alphabet.If the user Trace the alphabet in right way then a sound comes giving good othervise tracing will be there but the try again sound comes.

I am able to trace bt not able to detect if tracing is in right direction or not.Please help me out for this..